# Select Properties From CSS Class

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a way to select properties of a css class using Jquery?

```
example_class{
color: red;
font-size: 30px;
}

<span id="span1" class="example_class">Hello World!</span>
<span id="span2">Second Span</span>
```

What I actually need to do is get the color property of span1 and aply to span2.

Comment: You can always use `getDocumentByClassName`, get the first element that is returned, and access its `color` property.

Comment: @dayuloli: 1. If you mean `.style.color`, it wouldn't have the right value. 2. As the OP is using jQuery, it would be unnecessarily awkward.

Comment: @dayuloli The color property won't return properties inherited from stylesheets. The jQuery `.css()` method will get it.

Answer (score 3):

> What I actually need to do is get the color property of span1 and aply to span2.

jQuery's [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) gets the computed value of a property, and (when used as a setter) sets it on the element, so:

```
$("#span2").css("color", $("#span1").css("color"));
```

Example:

```js
$("#span2").css("color", $("#span1").css("color"));
```

```css
.example_class {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span id="span1" class="example_class">Hello World!</span>
<span id="span2">Second Span</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one last question, there is a way to add a class to a html element but without a property. Like... Add class "example_class" to "span2" but withouth the color property

Comment: @Avhelsing: Not directly. You'd have to add the class and override the property with an element-specific style (`$("#span2").addClass("example_class").css("color", "override-here")`), or add the class and another class that overrode the first class's color.